# Convert (rescale) 16 Bit png image

Tags: image-processing

I have a camera (12 Bit Sensor, 2048 * 2048 Pixels). The images can also be exported in 16 Bit png format. Here different settings can be used.

One setting is somewhat strange.

For this special case the corresponding exported image (http://goo.gl/Sk2pJT) contains all brightness values, but the histogram bars (here bin width 1) are 8 brightness values apart (rest is filled with zero brightness).

To illustrate the problem I have produced a histogram of the brightness values and displayed only the plot for the first Byte (0 to 255).

[image]

How can I rescale the image so that the histogram makes more sense (in the resulting histogram plot **each bar of bin width 1 should be attached to each other starting from 0**).

Is the following the right solution:

```
ImageAdjust[image, {0, 2^13}, {0, 2^16}];
```

For plotting the histogram of the `image` I have used:

```
imageData = Flatten[ImageData[image, "Bit16"]];
imageDataHistogram =
 Histogram[imageData, {1}, Frame -> True, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 255}, All}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"# of Pixels", ""}, {"Brightness [0,255]"}}]
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `imageData/8`?

Comment: It is caused by the lowest 3 bits of the data always being zero, and it is pretty much what I think one should expect for 12-bit data stored in a 16-bit format. Presumably one could also have e.g. a 14-bit camera, and this approach keeps the white and black levels the same while allowing for the possibility of more or fewer graduations between them. Since the binary logarithm of 8 is 3, and not 4, I guess the 12-bit data might actually be 12 bits plus sign, i.e. 13 bits in total. Anyway, @nikie's suggestion is just right for dealing with this, in my opinion.

Comment: Have you inspected your data carefully? It seems that image histogram leaves out values > 250, because the gap of 8 does not hold for all your data. Please look at `DeleteDuplicates[imageData] // Sort` and after that `BitShiftRight[% + 1, 3]`...

Comment: The reason that not all possible brightness values are existing is because the corresponding values (brightness) are not contained in the image. Imagine an image with only zero brightness pixels and a single pixel different from 0, then only two peaks would be seen in the histogram (when bin width is 1), one peak at zero and one corresponding to the brightness of the single pixel. All the rest bars in the histogram would not be there. 
For the upper image I get `Max[imageData] // N = 4095`.